# How to toggle multiple tabSlideOUt tabs on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabslideout

I need to use multiple `tabSlideOUt` [source](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/2655810) one one of the pages in a similar fashion as shown in [Fiddle Example](http://fiddle.jshell.net/pj52q07p/2/)

I need to toggle between tabs and only one should be open at a time

```
 $(function () {
     $('.slide-out-div').tabSlideOut({
         tabHandle: '.handle', //class of the element that will be your tab
         pathToTabImage: 'http://www.gac.com/upload/GAC2012/images/facebook_icon_50x50.png', //path to the image for the tab (optionaly can be set using css)
         imageHeight: '50px', //height of tab image
         imageWidth: '50px', //width of tab image    
         tabLocation: 'right', //side of screen where tab lives, top, right, bottom, or left
         speed: 300, //speed of animation
         action: 'click', //options: 'click' or 'hover', action to trigger animation
         topPos: '50px', //position from the top
         fixedPosition: false //options: true makes it stick(fixed position) on scroll
     });


 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by making some changes to HTML and and using updated js for slid-out. used js one that is on fiddle otherwise it might break.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/zy62umw5/1/

```
<div class="slide-out-div tab"> <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>

     <h3>Contact me</h3>
 <a href="mailto:wpaoli@gmail.com">wpaoli@gmail.com</a>

    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.</p>
    <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
<div class="slide-out-div tab2"> <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>

     <h3>Contact me</h3>
 <a href="mailto:wpaoli@gmail.com">wpaoli@gmail.com</a>

    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.</p>
    <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
<div class="slide-out-div tab3"> <a class="handle" href="http://link-for-non-js-users">Content</a>

     <h3>Contact me</h3>
 <a href="mailto:wpaoli@gmail.com">wpaoli@gmail.com</a>

    <br />
    <br />
    <p>Thanks for checking out my jQuery plugin, I hope you find this useful.</p>
    <p>This can be a form to submit feedback, or contact info</p>
</div>
```